# out of memory error, java heap space

Tags: java, heap-memory

I try to read log file with more than 4 million lines and size more than 400 MB, but I get **Out of Memory Error : java heap space**. This is my code :

```
File file = new File("C:\\file.log");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
        }
```

I tried to increase heap memory to 1GB, but still get that message. What would be the possible cause?

Comment: Don't store the entire file in a StringBuffer... what are you trying to do with the file contents?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If he has increased to 1GB and the file is only 400MB - would it still fail?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : I try to split it with specific parameter

Comment: Split it with what parameter. Do what with the split parts?

Comment: @user2310289 Apparently.

Comment: sorry, I mean with specific String and anaylze the split part

Comment: What do you want to do with read data? transfer,analyze?

Comment: @SatheeshCheveri : split it then analyze it...

Comment: Is this the only code..Means if you are doing something with this data in some other code, please mention. because this code should not cause OOM.

Comment: @VineetKasat : I'm using netbean and error message point to line 42 `stringBuffer.append(line);`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok, you already should have a clue, reading the comments you got.

Problem explanation:

Your log file has a size of 400MB. Note, that this is measured in bytes. Now you are reading it line by line with `line = bufferedReader.readLine()` thus converting some bytes to a string.

A `String` instance in Java internally holds a `char[]`. But a `char` in Java takes 2 bytes! So you need at least 800MB of heap space just for storing all the characters. As you are also allocating several other objects, and the JVM itself needs some memory, it is very probable that 1 GB is not enough.

Additionally, the `StringBuffer` (by the way: better use `StringBuilder` for that) internally uses again a `char[]`, which is expanded (in length) automatically when needed. This expansion is done by doubling the length. So for a 400MB file it has a `char[]` with a length of 512M. Still remind: A char takes 2 bytes.

So what is the solution? Simply put: Do not read the entire file into memory!

Do that instead:

```
class LogAnalyzer {
    private final File logFile;

    LogAnalyzer(File logFile) {
        this.logFile = logFile;
    }

    void analyze() throws IOException {
        try(FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(logFile)) {
            try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    analyzeLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void analyzeLine(String line) {
        // do whatever you need here
    }
}
```

If you need to keep some lines, you should store them in some instance fields of the LogAnalyzer, and/or have this class behave like a state machine.